# How to enable Nvidia graphics card in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, gpu

I bought an RTX 3070 for my desktop but can't seem to get my desktop to use it. It sees it but `watch nvidia-smi` shows it's off

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P8    14W / 220W |    198MiB /  7972MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       904      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1484      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 54MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1650      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               74MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2218      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2421      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2465      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2571      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2607      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2971      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            3MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm using the driver nvidia-driver-460 which is installed and enabled (done using GUI)

In addition, tensorflow detects the GPU but it takes a lot longer than it should to perform simple training operations (I have cuDNN and CUDA toolkit installed) and the load on the GPU as shown in the terminal doesn't increase at all.

It's my only GPU as far as I know, `lspci | grep VGA` returns only `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2484 (rev a1)`

additional info: I'm using gdm3 and have wayland disabled

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002484sv00001462sd00003909bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-465 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

```
ubuntu-drivers list
```

```
nvidia-driver-465, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-465-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-460-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-460-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-460, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04)
```

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

So how can I get my desktop to use my GPU?

Thanks

Comment: I'd try the 465 driver from the standard repos first, then if that fails, the latest one from graphics-drivers PPA, and if that fails, the latest from Nvidia.